# SharePoint Designer workflow InfoPath form with attachment control

Tags: javascript, infopath, designer-workflow, attachments

We have an InfoPath 2013 form created by a SharePoint designer workflow. We would like to add an attachment control to the InfoPath form. We understood that by design it is not possible to add such a control to an InfoPath form.

Is there perhaps a way to add custom javascript to the InfoPath form (e.g. sharepoint javascript object model) and let the form trigger the code when the user hits submit?

The aim is to have a user add a document to the InfoPath form. The document will then be posted to a document library.

What would be the approach here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no approach to upload attachment in document library using Workflow.

But we can do alternate solution like mentioned below:

1. Attach `ItemAdded` event on form library, where InfoPath form is
   created by workflow.
2. Read xml file(InfoPath form) using `OpenXML`(C# code)
3. Your file is stored in `base64binary` format in XML file, read it
   using `XMLNode`
4. Upload file in document library (C# code)

Comment: Thanks Viraj. However, do I need visual studio for this? The form is generated by a SharePoint Designer workflow (i.e. it is a task form).

Comment: Yes you require visual studio. Make wsp file and deploy solution. On feature activation, event receiver will attach to form library.